# GRUB Editing not working, leaving R9 390 on a dark screen

Tags: boot, grub, amd

I use an MSI R9 390, the card is famously unoptimized and needs GRUB edits for injection of kernel arguments `radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.dc=1` to work correctly with AMDGPU open source drivers, this worked fine in Beta 1-2, but when clean installing to the newest full release it seems to not change anything after `sudo update-grub` since the usual behaviour of the patch being missing takes place (black screen and monitor disconnection after or during password greeting screen)

It's been installed on a baremetal GPT layout 256gb SSD, CPU is an FX-8350

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by updating grub via the usual GRUB 2 method  `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, caught me off-guard because even during the beta the normal "`sudo update-grub`" worked.